# Angular 2 - scripting expression as a string

Tags: angular, scripting, kendo-grid, angular2-template

I am working on my basic table in my angular 2 application. I want to make a possibility to create icon expressions in my childs (where I call my basic table) and use them in my basic table.

For each children where i use my basic table, I have to declare an array of columns.

```
{ name: 'Bordero Typ', prop: 'borderoType', iconExpression:"dataItem[column.prop] == 'Delivery' ? 'fa fa-long-arrow-left' : 'fa fa-long-arrow-right'"}
```

I am using kendo grid for my table and have different templates for my columns.
I created the following template for my icon expression.

```
<kendo-grid-column *ngIf="column.iconExpression"
  field="{{column.prop}}" title="{{column.name}}" width="{{column.width}}" 
  [headerStyle]="{'font-size': fontSizeHeaderVal, 'padding': paddingTableVal }"
  [style]="{'font-size': fontSizeTableVal, 'padding': paddingTableVal}">
     <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <div>
          <i class="{{column.iconExpression}}"> </i>
       </div>
     </ng-template>
```

But it doesn't work. For angular this is a string and no expression and so there will be no result. If i write {{column.iconExpression}} in my template, it will show me the whole string and not the result of the expression.

Edit:

I have a bordero component which calls my table.

bordero.component.html:

```
<app-locoso-table *ngIf="finishedLoadingBorderos" [tableColumns]="columns" 
    [tableData]="locosoDataService.get('borderos')"
    [rowHeight]="28" style="font-size: 10pt; vertical-alignment: center" 
    (clickEvent)="onSelectElement($event)" 
    [tableHeight]="heightOfPrimaryElement">
</app-locoso-table>
```

My columns are in an array in the file bordero.component.ts:

```
private columns = [{ name: 'Bordero Typ', prop: 'borderoType', iconExpression:"dataItem[column.prop] == 'Delivery' ? 'fa fa-long-arrow-left' : 'fa fa-long-arrow-right'"}]
```

Transferring the column into the table is not the problem, my problem is how to say: hey angular2, this is an expression and not a string ;)

Comment: where is column defined?

Comment: i edited my post

Comment: assuming your kendo code is defined in bordero.component.html as well, then your ngIf on kendo-grid-column should use "columns" not column..... or if its in another file, how are you passing it down?

Comment: no my kendo code is in locoso-table.component.html, i'm sorry.
in my locoso-table.component.ts i have a @Input() tableColumns, which i set in my bordero.component.html ([tableColumns]="columns") and use in my locoso-table.component

Comment: ok then how are you passing column in your locoso-table.component

Comment: transfer my column into the table is not the problem, my table will show it as string, my problem is that i don't know how i can say: hey angular, this is a expression not a string! :)

Comment: if in your locoso-table.component column is defined properly as array or object, you don't have to tell angular explicitly, your ngIf looks good. it should pick it up, unless it doesn't know what column is. try to print it on the screen in <p> tag in html to see whats inside it. Thats the only thing i see

Comment: You can use val("string") to execute a string as javascript. But!!!! Watch out for injection!